# Why doesn't my IE8 specifc stylesheet correct browser styling?

Tags: css

I am doing some fine tuning of a PSD to xhtml conversion and tweaking some of the IE8 styles - or at least trying. I have an IE7 and IE8 stylesheet, but for some reason, IE8 doesn't respond to my style changes. I did some drastic font color changes, but even that doesn't respond.

I have confirmed that the stylesheets are on the server and made sure that the page validates, but no dice.

Here is the [page](http://www.theideapeople.com/projectpath/ideapeople-new/inside1.html):

Here is the meta information:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="_css/filter.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.css"/>
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link href="_css/ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <link href="_css/ie8.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Here is an example of something I tried to change just to see if it is connecting:

Standard CSS:

```
#intro #blurb h2     { font: bold 31px color: #fffeff; margin: 10px 0 10px 20px; }
```

IE8 styling:

```
#intro #blurb h2     { font: bold 31px color: #ff2500; margin: 10px 0 10px 20px; }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check:

- Does the file exist (has it been uploaded?)
- Is the file not loaded from cache? (only for non-local pages)
- Does your stylesheet contain syntax errors? (use http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)

To check whether the problem is in the CSS or the conditional comment, use:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    This should displayed in IE8 only.
<![endif]-->
```